# How to call Number Picker onvaluechange method from button onclick?

Tags: android, android-number-picker

NumberPicker in xml:

```
<NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/np"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
```

And here is button:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:padding="30dp"
    android:text="Any text!"
    android:background="@drawable/round_button" />
```

OnValueChangedListener on numberpicker:

```
//Set a value change listener for NumberPicker
    numberPicker.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal){

            //Statement goes here...

        }
    });
```

Whenever user changes the value, the statements in onvaluechange execute like they should. But I want to update the value of number picker using a button.

Now, I have set a onclicklistener to button:

```
b1 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Increment NumberPicker value by 1
            numberPicker.setValue(numberPicker.getValue() + 1);
        }
    });
```

This works, it increments the value of number picker by 1 but it doesn't notify the numberpicker that the value has changed so as a result, the code inside `onValueChange()` doesn't get executed. Only when the user manually scrolls the number picker does the statements execute. I want the same to happen when button is clicked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually a correct behavior of `NumberPicker` widget.
If you look inside its source code, you will see this:

```
public void setValue(int value) {
    setValueInternal(value, false);
}
```

and here is `setValueInternal` method:

```
private void setValueInternal(int current, boolean notifyChange) {
    if (mValue == current) {
        return;
    }
    // Wrap around the values if we go past the start or end
    if (mWrapSelectorWheel) {
        current = getWrappedSelectorIndex(current);
    } else {
        current = Math.max(current, mMinValue);
        current = Math.min(current, mMaxValue);
    }
    int previous = mValue;
    mValue = current;
    updateInputTextView();
    if (notifyChange) {
        notifyChange(previous, current);
    }
    initializeSelectorWheelIndices();
    invalidate();
}
```

as you can see `setValueInternal` is called by `setValue` method with **notifyChange = false** and this is why your listener doesn't get notified. `setValueInternal` is declared as private so you can't call it from your code without using reflection.

My suggestion is to do something like this:

```
private class NumberPickerListener implements NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener {

    @Override
    public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
      //your code
    }
}
```

then just declare a NumberPickerListener variable and use it inside your click listener:

```
final NumberPickerListener numberListener = new NumberPickerListener();
numberPicker.setOnValueChangedListener(numberListener);

b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int oldValue = numberPicker.getValue();
        numberPicker.setValue(oldValue + 1);
        numberListener.onValueChange(numberPicker, oldValue, oldValue+1);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks to pointing out to this. Really odd that almost all Android components notify listeners even on manual changes, but NumberPicker doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

Have a separate variable for listener

```
NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener np_listener = new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal){

            //Statement goes here...

        }
    }
```

How to set

```
numberPicker.setOnValueChangedListener(np_listener);
```

Usage

```
b1 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        //Increment NumberPicker value by 1
        numberPicker.setValue(numberPicker.getValue() + 1);
       // use it here np_listener 
    }
});
```